# Macbook and external hard drive : A better solution?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, windows, external-disk

I have an external hard drive. I use windows and macbook both. The problem is, plugging and unplugging from Mac is very much pain. If I accidentally remove it without 'ejecting', Mac doesn't recognise is next time I plug in. This is a very irritating problem and it keeps coming. Sometimes, while moving laptop here and there, connection gets loose and hard drive gets unplugged without 'safely ejecting'. Windows only warns, but recognises it every time I plug it in. Please suggest a solution. I don't wanna do all commandline stuff to make it work each time.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to use this drive for? Storing Documents, Backup, etc?

If you have a router with an usb port you could use this to set it up as a network drive that you can automatically connect when you login.

Answer (score 0):

If one of your computers never moves then you can leave the usb drive connected to it and do a network share like @MSa suggested.

Here is how to share from OSX to Windows
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24950/how-to-share-a-folder-in-os-x-with-windows/

And the other way around
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18709?locale=en_US